# How to print tabs according to row number

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program to output a set of 2 arrays entered by the user. It's a poem generator, the user enters a number of nouns followed by a number of adjectives, then my program combines an adjective with a noun randomly and displays it on the screen. A noun or an adjective cannot be chosen again after being already displayed. My problem is that I have to print a certain amount of tabs according the the rows, and then print the poem combination. For example, row 1 = 1 tab, row 2 = 2 tab, etc.

Here is a sample of the output desired:

https://postimg.org/image/5mp3niqvx/

And here is my code:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class A3Question1 
    {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean loop1 = false;
    boolean loop2 = false;
    boolean loop3 = false;
    int numNouns = 0, numAdjectives = 0;
    String[] nouns = new String[numNouns];
    String[] adjectives = new String[numAdjectives];

    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("           Let's write a poem!           ");
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
    System.out.println();

    while (!loop1)
    {
        System.out.print("How many nouns? (min 3): ");
        numNouns = keyboard.nextInt();

        if (numNouns < 3)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            loop1 = true;
        }

        System.out.println("Enter " + numNouns + " nouns: ");
        nouns = new String[numNouns];

        for (int i = 0; i < numNouns; i++)
        {
            nouns[i] = keyboard.next();
        }
    }
    while (!loop2)
    {
        System.out.print("How many adjectives? (min 3): ");
        numAdjectives = keyboard.nextInt();

        if (numAdjectives < 3)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            loop2 = true;
        }

        System.out.println("Enter " + numAdjectives + " adjectives: ");
        adjectives = new String[numAdjectives];

        for (int j = 0; j < numAdjectives; j++)
        {
            adjectives[j] = keyboard.next();
        }
    }

    while (!loop3)
    {
        System.out.println("\n-----------------------------------");
        System.out.println("        Here is my Java Poem!         ");
        System.out.println("           **LOOK AROUND**            ");
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
        System.out.println();

        boolean[] noDuplicate1 = new boolean[numNouns];
        boolean[] noDuplicate2 = new boolean[numAdjectives];

        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {               
            int num1 = (int) (Math.random() * numNouns); 
            int num2 = (int) (Math.random() * numAdjectives);

            if (noDuplicate1[num1] == false && noDuplicate2[num2] == false)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                {
                    System.out.print("\t");
                }
                System.out.println(adjectives[num2] + nouns[num1]);
                noDuplicate1[num1] = true;
                noDuplicate2[num2] = true;
            }
        }

        System.out.print("\nAnother poem? (y/n): ");
        String again = keyboard.next();

        if (again.charAt(0) == 'y' || again.charAt(0) == 'Y')
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            loop3 = true;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Thank you for using the POEM GENERATOR! Have a good day!");         

    keyboard.close();
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug in your code is this part:

```
for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
{
    System.out.print("\t");
}
```

Here, `i` is the number of iterations after which you found a non-duplicate noun and adjective.

Rather, add a new variable, called `numTabsToPrint` or something, that tracks how many tabs you have to print in each line, and increment it by one after printing each line.

Here's the changed snippet of your code, where I have explicitly commented on changed lines:

```
        boolean[] noDuplicate1 = new boolean[numNouns];
        boolean[] noDuplicate2 = new boolean[numAdjectives];

        int numTabsToPrint = 0;                             // Tracks number of tabs to print on each line.

        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {               
            int num1 = (int) (Math.random() * numNouns); 
            int num2 = (int) (Math.random() * numAdjectives);

            if (noDuplicate1[num1] == false && noDuplicate2[num2] == false)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < numTabsToPrint; j++)    // change 'i' to 'numTabsToPrint' in your original code.
                {
                    System.out.print("\t");
                }
                System.out.println(adjectives[num2] + nouns[num1]);
                noDuplicate1[num1] = true;
                noDuplicate2[num2] = true;
                numTabsToPrint++;                           // increment after printing current line.
            }
        }
```

Working example of the complete code can be found here: http://ideone.com/Gf71Ty